# Nginx - Redirect all previous subdomain's sub directories to main domain's subdirectories

Tags: nginx

In Nginx, I'm looking to redirect my `blog.example.com` subdomain to a subdirectory of the main website (`example.com/blog`). The blog.example.com subdomain has a number of blog posts under that subdomain. And a number of links are pointing to this old URL and I'd like to set up a catchall redirect for all `blog.example.com/*` links (all subdirectory links of that previous subdomain) to now go to `example.com/*` (each post should be in the root directory of the example.com domain – not inside the `/blog` subdirectory for single posts).

I currently have the subdomain redirecting to `example.com` using:

```
server {
  server_name  blog.example.com;
  location / {
    return 301 https://example.com/blog;
  }
```

Anyone have any tips for setting up 301's for all subdirectories of the previous subdomain? (FYI: all pages already exist with the same name on example.com).

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exact redirects you want. Can you provide concrete example URLs what is the old URL and what is the destination URL for the redirect, for all different cases you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have two types of URI on the old site, one with an embedded `/` (i.e. a subdirectory) and one without (single post).

Something like this might work:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://example.com/blog$request_uri;
}

location ~ ./ {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The second location block uses a regular expression that matches any URI with a `/` in the second or subsequent position.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'm sorry if I was a bit unclear. I simply want all of the old subdomains single posts to now point towards the new root domain. Is there a way to redirect all old 'blog.example.com/single-post' to 'example.com/single-post' without manually adding each post url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the redirect:

```
server {
    server_name blog.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This rewrites every URL like `https://blog.example.com/blog-post` to `https://example.com/blog_post`.